# Iseries qshell db2 truncate

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, truncated

I'm on iseries V7. I'm trying to use the qshell db2 command with large data.

My command under qshell (strqsh):
$ db2 "select data from mytable" 
Works fine except when data is bigger than 4096 characters : in that last case the output is always truncated to 4096 bytes (batch or interactive have the same behaviour)

Anyone as any clue about how to deal with date larger than 4096 characters ?
(After many researches on Stdout, pipe, PIPE_BUF, Rfile, db2 limitation, ... I can't find any valuable reason why my datas are always truncated)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Gwenaeld

Comment: Most likely it's just how the Qshell db2 utility is written. PIPE_BUF is 32K, at least through i 6.1; and I'm not sure any other limits apply. Since the db2 utility formats "reports", I'd wonder if it's just an artificial limit that assumes no printer used for SQL "reports" is likely to have lines that wide. Perhaps if you described your objective rather than the technical problem (that might have no fix), alternatives could be suggested.

Comment: Assuming that this is a permanent limitation, have you considered using REXX or QMQRY for ad-hoc SQL?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I've got a physical file with many columns and I'm trying to make un XML file with all the columns/data. An easy and elegant way I found was to use SQL with xmlelement/xmlserialize functions and it works very well with tools like Squirrel but when it comes to "batch it" on Iseries, I've got this issue.

Comment: Another option to run SQL commands is to use the JDBC Client included in jt400.jar.   Just "pipe" the sql statements into the client as follows.      echo 'select * from sysibm.sysdummy1' | java -cp /qibm/proddata/http/public/jt400/lib/jt400.jar com.ibm.as400.access.jdbcClient.Main jdbc:db2:localhost

Comment: Ah. So you're simply trying to generate XML of a DB2 table in batch, with the XML file stored in an IFS directory? And you tried to do it with the Qshell db2 utility?

Comment: Thanks to everybody ! I'll keep in mind the java solution for later !

The solution i found this morning was to do some substring in SQL like this: 
     select substr(data, 1, 4094) concat '##', substr(data, 4095, 4094) concat '##' from mytable 

After that i glue all the data with sed : sed ''s/## //g''

Not very elegant but it works for me !

Comment: @user2338816 : exact !